# Can't commit my project with git

Tags: eclipse, git, commit

I'm using the eclipse plugin for git in order to commit my PHP projects.
Until now everything goes fine but suddenly when I commit i get the following error:

> Committing failed
>
> An internal error occurred
>
> Entry not found by path: //ms_system/.../file.php

I notice that some of the files in the commit list has an invalid path, instead of:

```
dcms_system/.../file.php
```

I get:

```
//ms_system/.../file.php
```

Which is obviously wrong.

How can I to fix it?

Comment: Do you have some unexpected symlink somewhere in your working tree?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## I'm creating this as a reference for my own future self

None of the above answers worked for me.
This is the only Q on SO (or even google) pertaining to this.

What did work, I think, was:

> ***Goto Git Repo View in eclipse -> rt click on your repo -> collect garbage***
>
> then **commit**

***PS:***
This might not have done anything but just documenting it

> I also was on the git shell (github shell) at the same time running
>   `git status` commands (that's all I ran) on the root of the repo. And
>   surprisingly found that there were no Staged/Unstaged changes,
>   eventually realizing that the problem was solved.

***PPS:***
If the above does not work:

> ***Goto Git Repo View in eclipse -> rt click on your repo -> collect garbage -> rt click on your repo -> clean,*** then ***commit***

Comment: I required another step: Goto Git Repo View in eclipse -> rt click on your repo -> collect garbage -> rt click on your repo -> clean, then commit

Comment: @tricknology care to edit/update the answer? I'm not using eclipse anymore.

Answer (score 4):

I manage to solve this problem:

1. I change the problematic folder name to something else
2. Commit
3. Change the problematic folder name to the old one
4. commit

Not a recommend solution but it`s working now.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem.  I was receiving the same error because I was trying to commit files which were not added.  To resolve my issue I had to "Add To Index" prior to commit.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, it was solved by simply doing a refresh (F5) on the project.

Answer (score 0):

For me, none of the above answers worked. After experimenting, I found out that the conflicted file paths are listed as untracked files that you can choose to ignore in the commit page.

That is, go to the repo view in Eclipse -> right click on the repo -> commit -> show untracked files (selected by default) -> view files with erroneous paths and exclude them from the commit

[image]